# Getting 'Nsight Systems did not detect any NVTX traces' while running dlprof with pytorch

Tags: pytorch, gpu, profiling

I am getting the following error while running dlprof with pytorch.

```
Nsight Systems did not detect any NVTX traces.  Please check that you imported and initialized nvidia_dlprof_pytorch_nvtx in your script and try again. Refer to: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/dlprof-user-guide/index.html for more information.
```

Not sure how to do this importing and initialization correctly in the code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code like the following when using dlprof with pytorch.

```
import nvidia_dlprof_pytorch_nvtx as nvtx
nvtx.init(enable_function_stack=True)

with torch.autograd.profiler.emit_nvtx():
    training_loop()
```

This is taken from the [this](https://tigress-web.princeton.edu/%7Ejdh4/how_to_profile_with_dlprof_may_2021.pdf) document.